# Figuring out the class of an inheriting object

Tags: c++

I have a linked list of `Foo` objects.  Foo is a base class, which has several classes inherit from it.  Say, classes `A, B, and C`.

I am cycling through this linked list and calling a method `some_method`, which has 3 definitions; one for each child class:

```
some_method(A a);
some_method(B b);
some_method(C c);
```

The linked list is generic, so it is of type `Foo`, as it has an assortment of A, B and C objects.

When I'm cycling through the linked list at `current_element`, calling `some_method(current_element);`, how can I make it call the right method? The compiler complained until I wrote a some_method that took the generic `Foo`, and it only calls into that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you may want to consider using polymorphism.  To do this, add a pure virtual method to your base node class, and move the corresponding methods to the derived classes.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual void some_method() = 0;
};

class A : Foo
{
public
  virtual void some_method()
  {
    // move the body of some_method(A a) here
  }
};
```

For this to work, your linked list will need `Foo*`, instead of `Foo`.

```
class Node
{
public:
  Foo* foo;
  Node* next;
};

// ...

Node* someNode = GetNode();
// Calls correct method - A::some_method, B::some_method, or C::some_method
someNode->foo->some_method();
```

If you can't put `some_method` in Foo/A/B/C, then you might want to look into the Visitor design pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: This almost sounds right, but Foo does not have access to some_method, it is passed as a parameter to the method.  It is within a class which has a linked list of Foo pointers as a data member

Answer (score 2):

This is the "double dispatch" problem. You can use the visitor pattern. Usually the Visitor is a base class so you can re-use this design for multiple problems.

```
#include <iostream>
class FooVisitor;

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void some_method() = 0;
    virtual void visit(FooVisitor* v) = 0;
};

class A;
class B;
class FooVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(A* a){ std::cout << "A" << std::endl;}
    virtual void visit(B* b){std::cout << "B" << std::endl;}
};

class A : public Foo
{
public:
        virtual void some_method()
    {
        // move the body of some_method(A a) here
    }
    virtual void visit(FooVisitor* v) { v->visit(this);}
};

class B :  public Foo
{
public:
        virtual void some_method()
    {
        // move the body of some_method(A a) here
    }
    virtual void visit(FooVisitor* v) { v->visit(this);}
};

int main()
{
    FooVisitor fv;
    Foo* f1 = new A;
    f1->visit(&fv);
    Foo* f2 = new B;
    f2->visit(&fv);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: +1.  Visitor is a good pattern.  There are disadvantages to it (the visitor has to have a new method for each derived type, and thus has to be modified every time you create a new derived class).  But overall it can be a good choice in a problem like this.  I like your sample code.  This problem seems to be single dispatch, though, so the visitor pattern isn't strictly necessary (we don't need derived visitors).

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1) the better way:

Reverse your design such that someMethod is a virtual method of the base class Foo and redefine it in the derived classes. As:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        virtual void someMethod() = 0;
};

class A {
    public:
        void someMethod() { /* implementation specific to A here */ };
};

class B {
    public:
        void someMethod() { /* implementation specific to B here */ };
};

class C {
   public:
       void someMethod() { /* implementation specific to C here */ };
};
```

Then calling the someMethod on a pointer to `Foo` will automatically call the method from the appropriate class. If that cannot be done because `someMethod` cannot be implemented as part of `Foo` or its derivatives (e.g. it needs access to private members of the class it is currently in in your design), then you might try to split this functionality apart into subproblems that can be put into virtual methods of these classes `A` `B` `C`.

2) the "I don't have a choice" way:

Use RTTI (Run-Time Type Identification), it is included in C++. It requires that your base class Foo has at least one virtual method. You need to `#include <typeinfo>`, then use [typeid()](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/6402/) on the pointer, it will return a [type_info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/) object, and you can compare its `name()` result with the class names `A` `B` and `C`. This isn't a very nice approach because it has more overhead and it breaks OOP design principles. But if that's the only option, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

[RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) is your friend here. The example given in the link will guide you further

Comment: I'd only use RTTI as a last resort.  That last resort would be if I absolutely could not modify `Foo`.  Would upvote if there were an example and not just a link.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the method for the child class as a member method. For example`A a = new A(); a.some_method()` should call the correct the method. Within some_method() you can reference to object using keyword this.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but this doesn't seem like it would work.  I suppose I should clarify; A is a data member of where the linked list is stored.  An A object doesn't have access to some_method.  some_method is called with an A object as a parameter

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood, when you said "one for each child class" I guess I thought you meant each class contained a some_method() definition